# Langchain agent with custom tool stops after choosing the right tool

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

Have this custom tool build that uses an api endpoint (code for get_all works properly)

```
from langchain.tools import BaseTool
from _api_calls import get_all


class GetAllDocuments(BaseTool):
   name = "Get all documents"
   description = "This will trigger an API enpoint that will retrieve all documents from 
                 the database"

   def _run(self):
      return get_all()

   def _arun(self):
       raise NotImplementedError("This is not implemented yet")
```

Now the main file:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents import AgentType
from tools import clear_terminal
from _api_tools import GetAllDocuments
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
from dotenv import load_dotenv

clear_terminal()
load_dotenv()

llm = llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    temperature=0,
)

tools = [GetAllDocuments()]

agent = initialize_agent(
    tools, llm, agent=AgentType.STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True)

agent.run("Did we receive an invoice from Gucci?")
```

This is what I get in the terminal

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Thought: To check if we received an invoice from Gucci, I need to retrieve all the documents from the database and search for any invoices from Gucci.
Action: Get all documents


> Finished chain.
```

And then nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Btw when I define the tool in a different way:

@tool
def get_all_documents():
    """"This will trigger an API enpoint that will retrieve all documents from the database"""
    return get_all()

It works